# How do you pack multiple numbers into a single stat in a Rec Room circuit?

Tags: rec-room

Because Rec Room only gives us 6 player stats and 3 leaderboard stats, I don't have enough stats to store all the data that I want to store. Players in my game have multiple values that I would like to manage, and in order to actually store them I know I will need to pack them into a single stat.

What is the best way to do this? Ideally I'd like it to be a cheap solution that still can store a lot of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this that vary based on how much ink they will cost, what kinds of constraints you're working with, and how many stats you're trying to pack. The following solution achieves the tightest packing and costs (n-1)*2 chips for both packing and unpacking, where n is the number of values to store.

Say you have 4 values to store: a, b, c, and d. Each value has the following ranges. You know they will never be greater than or equal to this value.

```
a: [0, 30)
b: [0, 13)
c: [0, 25)
d: [0, 3)
```

Importantly, this method assumes that a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, and d >= 0; negative numbers will not work so you'll have to apply an offset before packing them and remove that offset after unpacking them.

Another important thing to check is that when multiplying the max values together, they do not exceed the maximum integer value of (2^31)-1.
In my example, that comes out to 29250 which is much less than (2^31)-1 so it can be stored safely in both a player stat and a leaderboard stat.

So to pack these values, you follow the following procedure:

```
accumulator = 0
accumulator = accumulator * 30 + a // this could be simplified to just "accumulator = a"
accumulator = accumulator * 13 + b
accumulator = accumulator * 25 + c
accumulator = accumulator * 3 + d
```

In Rec Room circuits, this looks as follows and can be investigated [here](https://rrcs.tk/circuit/ibi_a4aTB):
[image: Integer Packing]

Now to unpack you have to do the inverse:

```
d = accumulator % 3; accumulator = accumulator / 3
c = accumulator % 25; accumulator = accumulator / 25
b = accumulator % 13; accumulator = accumulator / 13
a = accumulator % 30; accumulator = accumulator / 30 // can be simplified to "a = accumulator; accumulator = 0"
```

In Rec Room circuits that looks as follows and can be investigated [here](https://rrcs.tk/circuit/rkcDLWz3v):
[image: Integer Unpacking]

That's the tightest encoding you can achieve with some nice benefits of being able to have arbitrary ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that with the example provided above, if you make the numbers bigger in the variable chip that has the numbers, 13, 25, and 3 it allows you to store bigger numbers until it gets weird, I don't know why but it works because I was having issues with it, the highest I could go with D was 2, C was 24, B was 12, and A was also 24 which are all one number lower than all of the numbers in the variable chip so that could be a connection too. Anyways if I went past any of those limits I just talked about they would reset back to 0 and the next number would have one more, but after I doubled each variable in the (13, 25, 3) chip it let me go a lot further