# Is there a way to reset the leaderboard for custom rooms?

Tags: rec-room

I am wondering if there is a way to reset the leaderboard, other than making the player trigger a circuit that sets leaderboard to 0.

My reason for asking is sometimes the previously mentioned solution isn't always plausible, especially when beta testing a server.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to reset the leaderboard is to file a support ticket. You can indicate specific users to reset if need be or whole entire stats. Use https://recroom.happyfox.com/new to file a ticket for leaderboard resets.

With a bit of planning, you can implement version numbers into your leaderboard stats such that you always know which players have stats that are utilizing outdated circuitry. Either allocate one of the stats or use [integer packing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363843/how-do-you-pack-multiple-numbers-into-a-single-stat-in-a-rec-room-circuit/363844#363844) to encode the version number into a multipurpose stat. Then, once your testing is done, you can increment the version number and your circuit will migrate everyone with an outdated version number.

Comment: What do you think of encoding a "version number of the circuit" in the data? When a circuit reads leaderboard data with a version number that is less than the current version number, then the circuit could reset the old data "on the fly".

Comment: Oh interesting... Would cost some overhead ink to encode and decode, but would ultimately be a valid way to reset the leaderboard during open beta testing.